# When GRidView's row is in edit mode, textboxes don't display current values

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

1) I noticed that if we don’t bind GridView to object data source control, then when user puts GridView into edit mode, we have to handle GridView.RowEditing event (else we get an exception ) and in this event put GridView’s row into editing mode. Is there a reason why GridView doesn’t automatically put a row into edit mode?

2) When we manually bind GridView to one of DataSet’s tables and user puts a row into edit mode, row’s columns will replace fields with text boxes. But for some reason these text boxes don’t display current field values, but instead they don’t display any text at all. What am I doing wrong?

3) I’ve also handled gridView.RowUpdated event, so I could put row back into non-edit mode,  but to no effect.   I even tried by pressing Edit button of some other row, but row still wouldn’t go out of edit mode. Any ideas what I’m doing wrong?

```
protected void gvwEmployees_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    e.KeepInEditMode = false; 
}
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

When not using a `DataSource` control with a `GridView` or other data-bound control which hide the complexity of the manual data-binding you must manually handle `RowEditing`, `RowUpdating`, and `RowDeleting` etc. With the built in data model and automatic binding the `GridView` handles these events for you.

You haven't posted your `RowEditing` code, but i suspect that you are not setting the GridViews `EditIndex` to the `NewEditIndex` and are not rebinding, this is probably why you are not seeing current data.

```
protected void gvwEmployees_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   GridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditINdex;
   BindData();
}
```

The same is true for your `RowUpdating` event. You will have to manually update your data, then set the `EditIndex` to -1, this will put your `GridView` back into `ReadOnly` mode. Keep in mind that `e.OldValues`, `e.NewValues` and e.Keys properties of the `GridViewUpdateEventArgs` are not populated when binding manually. This mean you'll have to take care of the update yourself by using `e.RowIndex` which is the index of the edited row.

```
protected void gvwEmployees_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridView.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}
```

Comment: A) Why do you have to rebind when GridView changes mode back to read only? I thought if GridView has ViewState enabled, then it will be able to restore field values ( for read only mode ) from ViewState?! B) Similarly, why when we put GridView into edit mode, must it be rebinded to data source? Couldn’t it take the values from read-only mode and apply them to fields in edit mode? “The same is true for your RowUpdating event. You will have to manually update your data, then set the EditIndex to -1, this will put your GridView back into ReadOnly mode.” I’ve tried it, but nothing happens